# How can i get glibc source code ？

Tags: system-installation

i have download one source code (glibc，linuxthreads） form GNU site .and install it in `/usr/local`.

I want to compiler glibc and change some code ，but i don't know where can download the source code.
question:

1. is other program  need？
2. how can i install it？

Comment: You have *installed* (?) the source code in `/usr/local`? How and why?

Answer (score 0):

Start here: https://launchpad.net/glibc

You will find packages and versions for various releases and architectures of Ubuntu. Each of these comes as a tarball that you can modify as needed.